# SQL Server CLR vs Python vs R

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Can somebody please explain the various scenarios that would make one choose SQLCLR vs Python vs R.

I understand that R is a language and a library specifically designed for statistical analysis and data mining so I understand leveraging that capability when appropriate, but can R (on SQL Server) do more and call additional external libraries like CLR assemblies can?

Is Python meant as an eventual replacement for C# SQLCLR?  It seems to me, from what I've read, that Python can simply be embedded inside a stored procedure and then interpreted upon execution as opposed the compiled nature of CLR assemblies, but otherwise the capabilities are the same? Are they?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions:

SQLCLR was introduced in SQL Server 2005, as a way to embed CLR (.NET) in the SQL Server engine. E.g with SQLCLR your .NET code is running in the same memory and process space as SQL Server itself. The way it works (simplified) is that you create an assembly and registers it with SQL Server (`CREATE ASSEMBLY`). You then create "wrapper" T-SQL stored procedures/functions/triggers etc., against your .NET methods, and it is these procs that you execute at runtime.

R was introduced in SQL Server 2016, and Python in SQL Server 2017 in order to give SQL Server machine learning capabilities. As opposed to .NET, neither R nor Python run embedded in SQL Server, but when you call R/Python code inside SQL Server, calls are made out to the R/Python engine sitting outside SQL Server's memory/process space. This is an important distinction between SQLCLR and R/Python:

- SQLCLR code executes in-memory/in-process with SQL Server
- R/Python executes outside of SQL Server.

As a side note; I have a series of [blog-posts](http://www.nielsberglund.com/2017/03/18/microsoft-sql-server-r-services-internals-i/) discussing the internals of SQL Server R Services (even if the posts talk about R, everything in there are applicable to Python as well).

As for capabilities; R/Python in SQL Server can do no more, no less than what "standalone" R/Python can do: as mentioned above the actual execution of R/Python happens outside of SQL Server as well.

Personally I do not think Python is a replacement for .NET in SQL Server, I see it as an additional tool in your toolbox. Where I work we use both SQLCLR as well as R/Python (in SQL Server). We have 100's of SQLCLR assemblies in our production databases, doing weird and wonderful things (sending messages to RabbitMQ etc., etc.), and IMHO it'd be very hard to replace that with Python, especially seeing that you'd immediately get a perf degradation - compiled code (SQLCLR) vs. interpreted code (R/Python).

Hope this helps.

Niels